# Base class 'Interpreter' has no non-destructor virtual functions

Tags: c++, lint

This is a part of my code:

```
class Interpreter {
public:
    Interpreter() : m_id_counter(0) {}
    virtual ~Interpreter() {}
protected:
    int32 m_id_counter;
};

class ManCal : public Interpreter {
public:
    ManCal() {}
};
```

and having the warning:

```
Warning: Base class 'Interpreter' has no non-destructor virtual functions
```

What is the reason ?

Comment: It's trying to tell you that you probably didn't want the destructor to be `virtual` either. Why did you make it `virtual`?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code, although it's hard to think of a use case for a base class that has a virtual destructor but no other virtual member functions.

Comment: @Simple: What's so hard about that? I find it harder to think of a useful base class that doesn't have a virtual destructor.

Comment: @Axel well what would you do with it? A virtual destructor implies you're going to have pointers to the base class so you can delete it polymorphically afterwards; if it has no other virtual members then you can't do much with those pointers.

Comment: @BoBTFish: There are several code-generators that produce classes with virtual destructors by default, for example I'm _fairly_ certain Rational Rhapsody (a UML design tool) does it.

Comment: @Simple: I could think of a smart pointer class. Create a factory to create those pointers. You then have the possibility to switch to a logging version of those pointers at runtime by returning a derived logging smart pointer instead of the base class. (Don't know if this is the best example, but I'm sure there are others.)

Comment: PS: Perhaps "object handles" would be better than "smart pointers" in my above example. Using pointers to smart pointers really sounds a bit off...

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the code.  The warning is just informing you that you created an inheritance relationship which has no possibility of overriding any base type behavior.  Often this is as sign that inheritance is inappropriate here and another pattern like "has a" would be more appropriate between `ManCal` and `Interpreter`